# programmatically adding contact in iphone contact list

Tags: iphone, list, sdk, directory, contacts

I want to programmatically add contact to iphone contact list without using ABNewPersonViewController. I would simply like to pass parameters and want the ABRecordRef as result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ABGroupAddMember (group, contact, nil) ;
ABAddressBookSave(inAddressBook, nil) ;
```

After adding the contact save the address book.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool ABAddressBookAddRecord (
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
   ABRecordRef record,
   CFErrorRef *error
);
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook